# Who will remove orbiting space debris?

Tags: geosynchronous

How long until we have something orbiting that can collect up the dead space debris in geosynchronous orbit and make way for new things to be placed in orbit?

Comment: No one can answer this question as written. You could edit it to ask about possible means of removing debris, or if there are any plans to do so.  But to ask who will do it, and when, makes too many assumptions.

Comment: There is a lot of space left in geosynchronous orbit. Just calculate the circumference. All newer GEO satellites should leave for a graveyard orbit at the end of their lifetime. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_orbit).